# Permission to drop database with DropCrateDatabaseIfModelChanges<>

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I am building a MVC solution, but I am not able to modify my model without getting a database error.

My Initializer looks like this:

```
public class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The error says:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot drop the database 'hemabiobank', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

How can I get permission to drop the database? Is it the server provider that has made me unable to to drop it?

**Side question:** How do I avoid loosing data when I modify the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission to drop the database could be from a number of things. One the ones I could thing of is that the permissions you're using to access the database do not allow you to drop a database. Are you able to login to the management studio with those permissions and drop a DB through SQL.

In terms of avoiding losing data when modifying the model, you are correct in thinking about the seed model, but you can also use database migrations:

I wrote the following on another question but it is useful here too:

Migrations provide a way to update tables/columns etc. without losing all of your existing infrastructure.

To be able to modify your code first DB using migrations you first need to enable them. To do this, in the NuGet package console simply type Enable-Migrations and press return. Once you have done this, You can make any sort of change to your classes, Dbsets, context etc. and then update them by typing add-migration (migration name here). When you have done this you'll notice a folder is created in your project called 'Migrations' or something similar. Within this you'll see some .cs files which represent the code that will be applied when you want to update the database. To physically update the database after you've added a migration you need to run the Update-Database command in the console. This will alter the database structure without losing everything you've already achieved.

The reason you give each migration a name is that you're able to swap between migrations, so you could go back to a specific change and undo further changes if you need to. This is why you'll find a separate .cs file for each migration you add in the Migrations folder, so it knows how to apply changes.

You'll also notice a migration history table created in your database, this also represents your changes and it records the state of the database at the point of that migration.

Comment: I get this message: "Msg 3701, Level 11, State 1, Line 5
Cannot drop the database 'HemaBiobank', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." Do I need to contact the provider then?

Comment: If you can verify that it does exist and that you haven't made a typo anywhere then I would contact the provider as your connection permissions do not allow the entity framework to initiate a drop query. It would, however, be interesting to see if you can perform a migration. Seeding would be data into a new database but it is usually for repopulating sample data. Migrations allow a structure and data to be retain with changes made to the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Oliver. Ill give seeding a try before contacting the provider.

Comment: You mean Migrations? :P

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. EDIT: yes that's what i ment. :p

Comment: No worries. I will still reproduce the access denied error later when I'm at my dev environment so we can totally confirm as to why you received the first error and let you know the findings.